# Perl HTML::Treebuilder XPATH Table Tags with no ID/Name

Tags: perl, xpath

I want to extract some text which is present in a specific table cell in the HTML page.

Now, the problem is, this cell is present inside a table tag which has no ID/Name.

I am using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath to extract the value using XPATH expressions.

Here is how the HTML content looks like:

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>Some Text</td>
<td>The Text I want comes here</td>
</tr>
```

This is how my XPATH expression looks like:

```
@nodes=$tree->findnodes(q{//table[8]/tr/td[2]/text()});
print $_->string_value."\n" foreach(@nodes); # corrected, thanks mirod.
```

It does not display the output.

I have used, table[8] above since this is the eight table tag in the HTML page (assuming the index starts from 1).

Also, I have used td[2] since I want the innerHTML between the second td tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you remove the `text()` at the end of the XPath query? I would think that calling `string_value` on the td itself would be enough.

Also method calls are not interpolated in strings, so you need to write `print $_->string_value, "\n"`.

This will give you the text of the content, not the markup though. For that you would need to use `as_HTML`, and strip the outer tags (there is no method in HTML::Element that gives you the inner HTML):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( <DATA>);

my @nodes=$tree->findnodes(q{//table[1]/tr/td[2]});
print $_->string_value, "\n" foreach(@nodes); # text
print $_->as_HTML, "\n" foreach(@nodes);      # outerHTML



__DATA__
<html>
<body>
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>Some Text</td>
<td>The Text I want comes here with <b>nested</b> content</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. It is not working for me. I used your approach as well. Am I correct in using the index, table[8] since it is the 8th table tag in the HTML Document? There are multiple table tags in my HTML Document and I am able to access only one of them.

Comment: yeas, `table[8]` should be OK. Make sure that there is not an extra `tbody` between `table` and `tr`, maybe even use `//table[8]//td[2]`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that as well. It still won't work. Is there a way to send you the HTML page so that you can try? I will tell exactly what I need to extract. Please let me know, thanks.

Comment: I was able to figure it out with HTML::TableExtract. Using the depth and count of the table as, (1,1), I am able to extract all the fields :) However, it would have been great if we could do the same using XPath.

Answer (score 1):

The mirod approach should work for you.

But I recommend to use `findvalues` instead of `findnodes` if you need text  content.

Try to run this code and show output:

```
my @values=$tree->findvalues(q{//table[8]//tr[1]//td});
print $_, "\n" foreach(@values);
```